# Why is the left node being placed at an unreachable location so early into the program?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am sorry if there are stupid mistakes that are being made here, I am new to C and I am still trying to understand how pointers work and learn where things get placed in the memory.

Currently, I am trying to create a program which reads from an input file and prints out each line sorted by their ASCII values. The program starts out by parsing the command line and then it sets the flags based on what the user entered in the command line. So my issue here is that the while loop runs once and then the second time it runs, it crashes on the addTreeNode() function in the same line as the first "if" statement in the while loop in "else".

This is because there is a memory leak because the second node being added is being placed in 0x200, which is an unreachable address. Here are the main, addTreeNode(), and strcmpC() functions as well as the structs I am using:

```
typedef struct NODE{

char* line;
int count;
struct NODE *left, *right;

       }NODE;

typedef struct BST{

NODE *root;


      } BST;
```

Main...

```
void main(int argc, char **argv){

extern int optind;
extern char *optarg;

int cflag = 0, iflag = 0, oflag = 0;

char *usage = "bstsort [-c] [-o output_file_name] [input_file_name]";
int com;

FILE *fpointer_in;
FILE *fpointer_out;
char *filename_in;
char *filename_out;
int MAX_STRING_LENGTH = 100;

while((com  = getopt(argc, argv, "ci:o:")) != -1){


    switch(com){

        case 'c':
            cflag = 1;

            //p
            //What strings do we compare?

            break;





        case 'o':
            oflag = 1;
            filename_out = optarg;
            break;      

           }







                         }



    BST* binary_tree = malloc(sizeof(BST));
    filename_in = argv[argc - 1];

    fpointer_in = fopen(filename_in, "r");

    while(!feof(fpointer_in)){



        NODE* new_node = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        new_node->line = calloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH, sizeof(char));

        fscanf(fpointer_in, "%[^\n]", new_node->line);
        new_node->count = 1;

        addTreeNode(new_node, binary_tree, cflag);





                 }

    printTree(binary_tree->root);   


    fclose(fpointer_in);


/*      NODE* testN = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    NODE* testN1 = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    NODE* testN2 = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    NODE* testN3 = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    testN->line = calloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH, sizeof(char));
    testN1->line = calloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH, sizeof(char)); 
    testN2->line =  calloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH, sizeof(char));     
    testN3->line = calloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH, sizeof(char));

    strcpy(testN->line, "B");
    strcpy(testN1->line, "A");  
        strcpy(testN2->line, "C");  
    strcpy(testN3->line, "C");

    testN->count = 1; 
    testN1->count = 1;  
    testN2->count = 1;  
    testN3->count = 1;  

    addTreeNode(testN, binary_tree, 1);
    addTreeNode(testN1, binary_tree, 1);
    addTreeNode(testN2, binary_tree, 1);
    addTreeNode(testN3, binary_tree, 1);

     NODE* s = NULL;
     s = cpyNode(s, binary_tree->root);
     printTree(binary_tree->root);
      binary_tree->root = cpyNode(binary_tree->root, s);
     free(s);
     free(testN->line);
    free(testN1->line);
     free(testN2->line);
     free(testN3->line);
     free(testN);
     free(testN1);
     free(testN2);
     free(testN3);
*/
if(oflag == 1){


    fpointer_out = fopen(filename_out, "w");





    fclose(fpointer_out);
          }

          }
```

Here is the addTreeNode() function:

```
void addTreeNode(NODE* add, BST* tree, int cflag){



if(tree->root == NULL){
    tree->root = malloc(sizeof(NODE));//25 is a test var.
    tree->root->line = calloc(100, sizeof(char));//25 is a test variable.
    strcpy(tree->root->line, add->line);
    tree->root->count = add->count;

              }

else{//FIXME: Use size_t pointers so that you can later free the memory holding the hard-coded addresses.


    bool found = false;

    size_t pointer_backup, head_root_backup = (size_t) tree->root;

    while(tree->root != NULL && found == false){

        if(strcmpC(add->line,  tree->root->line, cflag) < 0){
            pointer_backup = (size_t)tree->root;                
            tree->root = tree->root->left;



                                    }
        else if(strcmpC(add->line,  tree->root->line, cflag) > 0){

            pointer_backup = (size_t)tree->root;
            tree->root = tree->root->right;
                                      }

        else if(strcmpC(add->line,  tree->root->line, cflag) == 0){

            tree->root->count++;
            found = true;

                                 }





                  }

    if(found == false){
         tree->root = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
         tree->root->line = calloc(100, sizeof(char));//25.
         tree->root =  cpyNode(tree->root, add); 


         NODE* connect_parent = (NODE*) pointer_backup;

        if(strcmpC(connect_parent->line, tree->root->line, cflag) > 0){

            connect_parent->left = tree->root;
                                      }

        if(strcmpC(connect_parent->line, tree->root->line, cflag) < 0){

            connect_parent->right  = tree->root;
                                        }       


              }

     printf("%s", tree->root->line);
     tree->root = (NODE*) head_root_backup; 
                   }


        }
```

Here is the strcmpC() function:

```
int strcmpC(char* str1, char* str2, int cflag){

char str1c[100] = "";
char str2c[100] = "";
strcpy(str1c, str1);
strcpy(str2c, str2);    

int str_itr;
int to_lowercase;

if(cflag == 0){

    for(to_lowercase = 0; to_lowercase < strlen(str1c); to_lowercase++){


        if(str1c[to_lowercase] > 64 && str1c[to_lowercase] < 91){

        //Capital letters go from 65 to 90 in the ASCII table
        //Lowercase letter go from 97 to 122
            str1c[to_lowercase] += 32;
                                    }               


                                        }



    for(to_lowercase = 0; to_lowercase < strlen(str2c); to_lowercase++){


        if(str2c[to_lowercase] > 64 && str2c[to_lowercase] < 91){

        //Capital letters go from 65 to 90 in the ASCII table
        //Lowercase letter go from 97 to 122
            str2c[to_lowercase] += 32;
                                    }               


                                        }            
         }

str_itr = 0;
while(str1c[str_itr] != 0 && str2c[str_itr] != 0){

    if(str1c[str_itr] < str2c[str_itr]){

        return -1;
                       }



    if(str1c[str_itr] > str2c[str_itr]){

        return 1;
                       }
    str_itr++;

                            }

if(str1c[str_itr] == 0 && str2c[str_itr] != 0){

    return -1;

                           }
else if(str2c[str_itr] == 0 && str1c[str_itr] != 0){

    return 1;
                           }

return 0;



                       }
```

I do not understand why there is a memory leak very early in the program. I the main, there is a block of code which is commented out in which I create 4 nodes and add them sucessfully and later prints them. There are no issues here, the nodes get added in their correct place and they get copied to another backup node and printed. But when I try to read the lines from an input file and create nodes from those lines, then my program gets this memory leak.

Please excuse the identation, I REALLY have no time to edit this code as I have to head to work but the assignment has to be turned in tonight. I had to open the file in VisualStudio even though I have been working on it in ocelot(A UNIX environment). The indentation in that file is better. Thank you guys VERY MUCH for your guys' help in advance!

Comment: One leak is the very first node: you malloc a node and its line, move the data in (side note: make sure the read succeeds and doesn't read in more than your max characters), and never frees that node. `addTreeNode` mallocs a new node and copies the data, instead of using the node itself.

Comment: Might also be cleaner to just use `NODE*` for copies, instead of `size_t`.

Comment: Please reformat your code so that it is indented in an orthodox style, and remove as many comments as possible, plus any other irrelevant material.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]), even before you (re)read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  As it stands, your code is nearly unreadable, which makes it hard to debug — for you, and for us.